# What is this process called: Analog input, with a analog output with setpoint

Tags: analog, control-system, pid-controller

What is this process called:

In my example the analog input represents line current. The analog output represents voltage. this is a closed loop with a target set point. The behavior would be that when the current level of the input is below the set point it would increase the output. When it went over the set point it would decrease the output.

My question is does this process have a name? I am told it is not a PID loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a control loop.  You can close the loop with a PID controller, but that is not the only choice.  What you described sounds most like a P controller that only uses the proportional (P) term.  That's basically the simplest possible control loop, and it can be sufficient for some applications.  When P control is not sufficient, usually some combination of I and D (integral and derivative) to improve the performance.  If that is  not enough, then you need to go study control theory.

Comment: No that answers my question, atleast initial question. I was confused because one of the Tech Support guys at Red Lion told me that is not what a PID control is. He said that all a PID controller does is turn the output on and off even with an analog output. He said that if it did what I wanted it was not a PID controller. And further said that what I wanted to do was impossible. Which I knew wasn't true.

Comment: This person you spoke to is vastly misinformed. I don't know what Red Lion is, but I hope this guy is not in a position to misdirect too many other people. To reduce the whole of PID control loop theory to nothing more than an on/off switch is tragic.

Comment: FTR: Red Lion is an industrial sensor and controls manufacturer.

Comment: ^ The world has come to an end if that's the case

Comment: Another example of incompetent tech support. Perhaps their title should be changed, to tech burden?

Comment: A controller that has an 'on-off' control output instead of a an analog or multi-bit digital output is called a 'bang-bang' controller.  This type of controller is used all over the place for things like heaters.  I think you can put a bang-bang output on a PID controller, but you may need to do a bit more work to get it stable so it doesn't oscillate.